# Selenium - Java - Unable to capture the Error popup that appears once in 12 times of test execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I execute my test cases minimum 15 times per day. There is a strange popup appears at least once per 15times and shows an Error. I need to validate this popup in my test case like,

1. If the popup appears, then fail the test case.
2. Capture the text present in the popup and pass it as failure message

I followed the below code and didn't work out. Whether the popup appears or not(i.e. in every execution), the test case is failed stating:  IllegalStateException: failure 'Offer is not created'. If the popup error comes the same message is shown but the text from the popup is not shown. I would like to display the text from both h4 tags.

```
public void CreateOffer() throws Exception {
  try
  {
      if ((FindTheElement("xpath", CreateOfferButton)).isDisplayed())
      {
            WaitAndClickOnElement("xpath", CreateOfferButton);
            WaitTillElementToBeDisplayed("xpath", TenderVersion);
            CheckOfferError();
      }
  }
  catch(Exception e) 
  {
      Assert.fail("Offer is not created");
        //CheckOfferError();
        //WaitTillElementToBeDisplayed("xpath", TenderVersion);
  }

}

public void CheckOfferError() throws Exception  
{   
   String Text=null;
    try   
    {


 if(FindTheElement("xpath",OfferErrorPopUp).isDisplayed() ) 
 {    
    WebElement PopUpError = FindTheElement("xpath",PopupError);

    Text=PopUpError.findElement(By.tagName("h4")).getText();
 } 
    }
    catch(Exception e)     
    { 
            Assert.fail("Offer error window appeared with the text: "+ Text);
    } 
}
```

HTML script for the error popup,

```html
<div class="modal-dialog-error">
    <h3 class="uc">Error</h3>
    <h4>ValidationError</h4>
    <h4>invalid offer data: ["offer id does not match the existing incomplete offer"]</h4>
    <button class="button-action uc">
    <!-- react-text: 13 -->OK<!-- /react-text -->
    </button></div>
```

For both the situation, the same below output is shown currently. I tried various ways and the above code is what I followed as final before posting here.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create Offer For The Opportunity                                      | FAIL |
IllegalStateException: failure 'Offer is not created'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me in correcting this code.

Comment: when the code calls Assert.fail() within a catch block, it might be helpful to pass along the actual exception that was raised.  This will help you to further debug why you're getting the first failure inside CreateOffer.

Comment: You don't see the text from the popup error because the CreateOffer code never gets that far.  Once you fix that, though, you'll need to update CheckOfferError so that it searches for ALL of those h4 element, right now, the code will just get the first one that it finds.

Comment: @Breaks Software - Thanks for the response. I corrected my code by removing the Assert.fail() from Catch block in CreateOffer() method. As needed, the message doesn't appear when the test case is pass. But still the TC is not failing when the error window appears. i.e. this situation also it is PASS. It must throw FAIL.

Comment: so, when the error dialog appears, the code does not find it?  You don't show the code for "FindTheElement()", does it wait for the target object to appear?  It should.

Comment: I was brainless. Finally I have brought up the output. Thanks @Breaks Software. Updated the corrected code in the Answer part. But still I couldn't bring the text from the second h4 tag. i.e. '<h4>invalid offer data: ["offer id does not match the existing incomplete offer"]</h4>' . Tried to follow many websites, but didn't work. Please suggest me how to bring this text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CheckForError() is only asking for the first h4 element.  You will want to get the full set.  Instead of:

```
        Text=PopUpError.findElement(By.tagName("h4")).getText();
```

you'll want to:

```
        allH4s = PopUpError.findElements(By.tagName("h4"));
```

Then use a loop to call getText() from each of those and consolidate to your returned Text.  (sorry, I haven't written Java for a year, so I can't come up with the actual code for you quickly)

Comment: Its perfect. Thanks a lot Breaks Software. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will resolve 1st concern "1. If the popup appears, then fail the test case."

```
public void CreateOffer() throws Exception {
  try
  {
      if ((FindTheElement("xpath", OfferPageData.CreateOfferButton)).isDisplayed())
      {
            WaitAndClickOnElement("xpath", OfferPageData.CreateOfferButton);                
            WaitTillElementToBeDisplayed("xpath", OfferPageData.TenderVersion);
            if((FindTheElement("xpath", OfferPageData.OfferPageName)).isEnabled())
            {
                try
                {
                ClickOnElement("xpath",OfferPageData.OfferPageName);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    CheckForError();
                    Assert.fail("Offer page is disabled");
                }
            }
      }
      else
      {
          CheckForError();  
      }
  }
  catch(Exception e) 
  {
      String Error = CheckForError();
      Assert.fail("Offer is not created. Error is: " + Error);
  }

}

public String CheckForError() throws Exception  
{   
  String Text=null;
    try   
    {

            WebElement PopUpError = FindTheElement("xpath",OfferPageData.PopupError);
            Text=PopUpError.findElement(By.tagName("h4")).getText();
        }
    catch(Exception e)     
    { 
            Assert.fail("Offer page is interrupted: ");
    }
    return Text; 
}
```

Output of the above code is,

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create Offer For The Opportunity                                      | FAIL |
IllegalStateException: failure 'Offer is not created. Error is: ValidationError'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```